# Code not working for bmi caclculation .Only one code block is working other is not working

Tags: java, android

When i click on 2nd spinner item the code of that particular spinner item should execute but its not being executed .Only one if part is being getting executed

I have tried the following code

```
package com.example.bmicalculator;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.shashank.sony.fancytoastlib.FancyToast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner gender_spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get the references to the widgets
        final EditText weight_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_et);
        final EditText height_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_et);
        final EditText height_et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ft_in_et);
        final EditText weight_et1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.st_lb_et);
        final TextView result_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_tv);
        final TextView ideal_weight = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ideal_weight);


        final Spinner height_spinner = findViewById(R.id.height_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_height = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Height,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_height.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        height_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_height);

        height_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        height_et.setHint("Height(cm)");
                        height_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);break;
                    case 1:
                        height_et1.setHint("in");
                        height_et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        height_et.setHint("ft");break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.ERROR,true).show();
            }
        });




        final Spinner weight_spinner= findViewById(R.id.weight_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_weight = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Weight,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_weight.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        weight_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_weight);

        weight_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        weight_et.setHint("Weight(kg)");
                        weight_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);break;
                    case 1:
                        weight_et.setHint("Weight(lb)");
                        weight_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);break;
                    case 2:
                        weight_et.setHint("st");
                        weight_et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        weight_et1.setHint("lb");break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                FancyToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG,FancyToast.ERROR,true).show();
            }
        });


        gender_spinner = findViewById(R.id.gender_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_gender = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Gender,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter_gender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        gender_spinner.setAdapter(adapter_gender);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                weight_et.setText("");
                height_et.setText("");
                height_et1.setText("");
                height_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                weight_et1.setText("");
                weight_et1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                result_tv.setText("");
                ideal_weight.setText("");

                height_spinner.setSelection(0);
                weight_spinner.setSelection(0);
            }
        });


        if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0 && weight_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){

            findViewById(R.id.ib1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                // Logic for validation, input can't be empty
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String Height = height_et.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Weight = weight_et.getText().toString().trim();

                    if(Height.isEmpty()){
                        height_et.setError("Please enter your Height");
                        height_et.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    if(Weight.isEmpty()){
                        weight_et.setError("Please enter your Weight");
                        weight_et.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }



//Get the user values from the widget reference
                    float weight = Float.parseFloat(Weight);
                    float height = Float.parseFloat(Height)/100;

//Calculate BMI value
                    float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
                    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                    String rounded_bmivalue= decimalFormat.format(bmiValue);
//Calculate Ideal Weight



//Define the meaning of the bmi value
                    String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                    if (bmiValue<16) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue<=17){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue>17 && bmiValue <18.5) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue>=18.5 && bmiValue <= 25) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));
                    }
                    else if ( bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue < 30) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >= 30 && bmiValue <35){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4500"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >= 35 && bmiValue <40){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }


                }
            });

        }

        if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1 && weight_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){

            findViewById(R.id.ib1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                // Logic for validation, input can't be empty
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String Height = height_et.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Weight = weight_et.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Height1 = height_et1.getText().toString().trim();

                    if(Height.isEmpty()){
                        height_et.setError("Please enter feet");
                        height_et.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    if(Weight.isEmpty()){
                        weight_et.setError("Please enter your Weight(in kg)");
                        weight_et.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (Height1.isEmpty()){
                        height_et1.setError("Please Enter inches");
                        height_et1.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }



//Get the user values from the widget reference
                    float weight = Float.parseFloat(Weight);
                    float feet = Float.parseFloat(Height);
                    float inches = Float.parseFloat(Height1);
                    float height = convertftandin(feet,inches)/100;

//Calculate BMI value
                    float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
                    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                    String rounded_bmivalue= decimalFormat.format(bmiValue);
//Calculate Ideal Weight



//Define the meaning of the bmi value
                    String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                    if (bmiValue<16) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue<=17){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue>17 && bmiValue <18.5) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue>=18.5 && bmiValue <= 25) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));
                    }
                    else if ( bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue < 30) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >= 30 && bmiValue <35){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4500"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >= 35 && bmiValue <40){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }


                }
            });

        }





    }

    //Calculate BMI
    private float calculateBMI (float weight, float height) {
        return (float) (weight / (height * height));
    }


    //conversion of ft and in to cm

    private float convertftandin(float ft,float in){
        return ((ft*30.48f)+(in*2.54f));
    }

    //Calculate Ideal Weight


    // Interpret what BMI means
    private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {

        if (bmiValue < 16) {
            return "Very Severely Underweight";
        }
        else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue<=17){
            return "Severely Underweight";
        }
        else if (bmiValue>17 && bmiValue <18.5) {
            return "Underweight";
        }
        else if (bmiValue>=18.5 && bmiValue <= 25) {

            return "Normal";
        }
        else if ( bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue < 30) {

            return "Overweight";
        }
        else if (bmiValue >= 30 && bmiValue <35){
            return "Obese Class I";
        }
        else if (bmiValue >= 35 && bmiValue <40){
            return "Obese Class II";
        }
        else {
            return "Obese Class III";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_remove_ads) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When i click on 2nd spinner item the code of that particular spinner item should execute but its not being executed .Only one if part is being getting executed
Following code is not working

````
if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==1 && weight_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){

            findViewById(R.id.ib1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                // Logic for validation, input can't be empty
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String Height = height_et.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Weight = weight_et.getText().toString().trim();
                    String Height1 = height_et1.getText().toString().trim();

                    if(Height.isEmpty()){
                        height_et.setError("Please enter feet");
                        height_et.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    if(Weight.isEmpty()){
                        weight_et.setError("Please enter your Weight(in kg)");
                        weight_et.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (Height1.isEmpty()){
                        height_et1.setError("Please Enter inches");
                        height_et1.requestFocus();
                        return;
                    }



//Get the user values from the widget reference
                    float weight = Float.parseFloat(Weight);
                    float feet = Float.parseFloat(Height);
                    float inches = Float.parseFloat(Height1);
                    float height = convertftandin(feet,inches)/100;

//Calculate BMI value
                    float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
                    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                    String rounded_bmivalue= decimalFormat.format(bmiValue);
//Calculate Ideal Weight



//Define the meaning of the bmi value
                    String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

                    if (bmiValue<16) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >=16 && bmiValue<=17){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue>17 && bmiValue <18.5) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue>=18.5 && bmiValue <= 25) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));
                    }
                    else if ( bmiValue > 25 && bmiValue < 30) {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ACD32"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >= 30 && bmiValue <35){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4500"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else if (bmiValue >= 35 && bmiValue <40){
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6347"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }
                    else {
                        result_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        result_tv.setText(String.valueOf(rounded_bmivalue + " - " + bmiInterpretation));

                        ideal_weight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    }


                }
            });```
````

Comment: Declare your spinner as global, you have to remove the final keyword. 

  

    height_spinner = findViewById(R.id.height_spinner);

Comment: Still not working @SamarthSevak

Comment: try to print (LOG) the selected index/position. Log.d("Clicked:", position);

Comment: @SamarthSevak where should i enter the log code

Comment: inside the spiner's item select listener

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, I think what you want to do is set the onClickListener for `R.id.ibl` depending on the Spinner selected.

However, the part that does that is not inside the listeners of the Spinner. That's why they don't execute every time you click that particular spinner.

Your code only executes the block of code under `if (height_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0 && weight_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)` because those are the initial values of your spinner.

You may want to put the block of code that sets the `onClickListener` of the `R.id.ibl` inside the Spinners' `onItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: but there are 2 spinners so its not possible

Comment: not working ...please anyone suggest fast what to do @ObiWeng